# Yarn ApplicationMaster Log location

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I enabled Yarn Log aggregation using Spark on Cloudera, but when the spark job failed, I run

```
yarn logs -applicaitonId <id>
```

or

```
yarn logs -applicationId <id> -am ALL
```

All I got are working logs in `stderr`

But in Yarn failure diagnose line, I managed to see

```
Diagnostics:    User class threw exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

The tricky part is I can't find this exception anywhere, including the `/var/log/hadoop-yarn` log folder location on each machine as well.

I need this exception details so that I could understand which Jar is missing or what exactly is going wrong with the spark environment settings.

Any ideas how I can find this log location? I found some similar questions with below logs:

```
17/08/16 02:28:06 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

Hence I was trying to locate the ApplicationMaster log location and maybe that's different from what we usually do on container logs.